# plugin and package scoped global variables

Tags: go, plugins

I have a Go package to manage configuration. The package has a non-exported variable initialized in an `init` function that holds the configuration data. The user interacts with the configuration through exported functions that internally access the global variable. Something like this

```
pakage config

var gConfig ...

func init() {
    gConfig = ...
}

func Value(name string) (string, error) {
    return gConfig.value(name)
}
```

I’m considering the use of plugins and explore the impact on my config package.

If the plugin imports the config package and calls some of its exported functions, what gConfig variable will be used? Will the plugin have its own internal instance of config with its own gConfig variable initialized when the plugin is loaded, or will the plugin be linked dynamically at load time to use the main program gConfig variable initialized at program startup?

Comment: Would it not be more explicit to have the config package export a struct that could be copied to the plugins?  I _think_ that the answer to your question is that they would all access the same variable, but I think if it does, there is a certain amount of magic with that design that would be hard to reason about for the un-initiated (which could be future you).  The more explicit it is, the more maintainable it is. FWIW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per documentation

> Package plugin implements loading and symbol resolution of Go plugins.
>   When a plugin is first opened, **the init functions of all packages not
>   already part of the program are called**. The main function is not run.
>   **A plugin is only initialized once, and cannot be closed**.

Also, you cannot import the same plugin twice.

> Will the plugin have its own internal instance of config with its own gConfig variable initialized when the plugin is loaded

the plugin will have its own variable within its scope.

> If the plugin imports the config package and calls some of its exported functions, what gConfig variable will be used ?

the variable defined within the package, as you demonstrated.

To check that out, write a small demonstration. Go is very straightforward and efficient, doing it takes very little time, see.

```sh
    $ tree .
    .
    ├── main.go
    ├── plug
    │   └── plugin.go
    └── plugin.so

    1 directory, 3 files
```

```golang
// $ cat plug/plugin.go 
package main

var pkgGlobal = map[string]string{}

func Set(k, v string) {
    pkgGlobal[k] = v
}
func Get(k string) string {
    return pkgGlobal[k]
}
```

```golang
// $ cat main.go 
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "plugin"
)

func main() {
    p, err := plugin.Open("plugin.so")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    var get func(string) string
    {
        x, err := p.Lookup("Get")
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        get = x.(func(string) string)
    }
    var set func(string, string)
    {
        x, err := p.Lookup("Set")
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        set = x.(func(string, string))
    }

    set("tomate", "rouge")
    fmt.Println(get("tomate"))
    fmt.Println(get("notomate"))
}
```

build and run

```sh
$ go build -buildmode=plugin -o plugin.so plug/plugin.go 
$ go run main.go 
rouge
```

Comment: Thank you for the effort to provide such a detailed answer. Unfortunately, it only partially answered my question. Using your code example, I implemented the precise use case I’m considering and could verify that the plugin did not have a copy of the global variable of the other package. I can thus use my configuration package from the plugin without conflicts. Thank you very much.